# Git help: Aborted git commit in Android, but changes are there in local not remote

Tags: git, android-studio, github

Folks

While commiting all my files to the remote github repository, I found the Android Git Commit/Push sucking some unwanted files(which I didn't want it to do). So I had to abort after all the checks completed (when it asked me "do you want to commit all these files").

The problem: The local repository shows that all commits are done -- no commits left (in a state where even Android says "no changes to commit" when I click on all the new files I have). The remote repository doesn't have any of the changes obviously.

I don't want to revert, since it deletes the nodes in my local repository. How do I ensure the files in my local repository now get pushed to remote ().

Comment: If you want everything in your local to be in remote do a force push

Comment: I want to be careful doing that, so can i do this file by file. If I do a git commit for example, I don't all the files in my local repository listed which are ahead of the remote. 
<hr>

git commit -m "new files for feature X"
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Changes not staged for commit:
 modified:   ../../../../../../../../.idea/modules.xml
 deleted:    ../../../../../../../../.idea/vcs.xml


<hr> but the local files don't show up

Comment: I see so many comments about not doing a force push on the remote repository. Can I go file by file and do this (I have only 17 files to push).

Comment: should i be using the git reset --mixed "Resets the index but not the working tree (i.e., the changed files are preserved but not marked for commit) and reports what has not been updated. This is the default action."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things that i have noticed.

If you just do,

```
git add .
git commit -am "Message"
```

Then it will say nothing to commit.

I think you might have forgot

git push or git add command.

Try again by doing

```
git add <files separated by space>
git commit -am "Clean push"
git push origin <branchname>
```

also check if you are in correct branch and pushing to correct branch.

Also use below command to know list of files what are not added to pushed to remote

```
git status
```

Comment: I think what happened was the git push never got executed in the Android studio. A work around I had was to touch the files and push them. That way they showed as needing a commit in Android. I tried a reset but it deleted the local files, and I had to revert to get back all my changes. But interestingly the local repo had all the changes, and said . "nothing to commit"

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can re-do your commit with:

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git reset @~
```

That will reset the index to your previous commit.

From there, you can:

- add some files to your `.gitignore`
- add again, and make a cleaner commit, for you to push.

Comment: If I do a reset, won't the local files get deleted? How can I do this (safe reset - -only in the repo index) without  deleting this files from my android project view. Last time I did a reset, these files no longer got displayed in my android project.

Comment: @Mr.hands-on No a mixed reset would not touch the working tree (your files), only the index (resetting the index to HEAD)

Comment: Ok. thank you for that input.  
git reset @~ is this an example of mixed reset?

I think this is going to be more useful moving forward. It is a combination of the git push and index so Both the responses from vonc and @naruto are helpful.

Comment: @Mr.hands-on No: git reset (without any --option) is mixed: no option means by default --mixed. @~ is just to reset to the previous commit.